# Alterar formato Data de uma instrução JSON de uma Controller

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Tenho uma Controller que gera uma saída no formato Json, abaixo indicado.

A data esta retornando isto no Json **2019-07-22T16:00:04.8579075**, quero que retorne **22/07/2019 16:00**

```
{
    ordemChegadaId: 1,
    data: "2019-07-22T16:00:04.8579075",
    ordem: 1,
    veiculoId: 29,
    getVeiculo: {
                  veiculoId: 29,
                  tag: "0x300833B2DDD9014000000029",
                  empresaId: 25,
                  getEmpresa: {
                                empresaId: 25,
                                nome: "J G DO VALE - TRANSPORTES ME"
                  },
                  motorista: "BENEDITO MARQUES DOS SANTOS",
                  placa: "AJW-5298",
                  tipoId: 2,
                  getTipo: {
                             tipoId: 2,
                             nome: "TRUCK"
                  }
          }
},
```

Controller

```
    // GET: api/OrdensChegadas
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OrdemChegada>>> GetOrdensChegadas()
    {
        return await _context.OrdensChegadas.Include(o => o.GetVeiculo).Include(t => t.GetVeiculo.GetTipo).Include(e => e.GetVeiculo.GetEmpresa).OrderBy(o => o.OrdemChegadaId).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Classe

```
 public class OrdemChegada
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrdemChegadaId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Data")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ordem")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]
        public int Ordem { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Veículo")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatório")]       
        public int VeiculoId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Veículo")]
        public virtual Veiculo GetVeiculo { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Por que? Assim deixará de ser uma data e será apenas uma string qualquer... Não seria apenas o caso de tratar a exibição dessa informação?

Comment: Provavelmente você vai ter que criar um serializador personalizado pra isso. O Leandro fez a pergunta correta: qual a necessidade disso? Remover informações da data pode ser prejudicial pra aplicação cliente. Se você tem ciência disso e quer realmente devolver neste formato eu aconselharia a criar uma classe intermediária para representar o JSON que será retornado e, nesta classe, trataria esta data como uma string — já que, neste caso, é justamente o que ela será.

Comment: Vocês estão totalmente corretos, esta saída JSON será utilizada em uma planilha Google e o script de captura é codificada em Python, estou tendo dificuldades no momento de realizar um Short Date, vou fazer uma nova pergunta.